# how to update value of key in json type field on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update

I am running postgresql 9.6 version. I am storing data in json type field.

```
insert into testable (name, jsonvalues) 
values("Jacky", "{'has_attachment': True, 'flag':'True'")
```

I want to update "flag" to "False".

What query i have to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
update testable 
set jsonvalues = jsonb_set(jsonvalues::jsonb, '{flag}', '"False"')::json
where name = 'Jacky'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ea304eadca6e8cbe4387a88434606047)**:

```
name  | jsonvalues                                 
:---- | :------------------------------------------
Jacky | {"flag": "False", "has_attachment": "True"}
```

Note that your original `insert` query is not valid Postgres syntax. You need single quotes around the values, and double quotes within the JSON, so that should be:

```
insert into testable (name, jsonvalues) values(
    'Jacky', 
    '{"has_attachment": "True", "flag":"True" }'
)
```